# NodeJS not receiving data from serialport

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port

I am able to get a list of serial ports, and successfully open my desired port. However, The data received event never fires. The port sends a small amount of data after being opened. I have verified that the port is sending data by using a usb monitor.

```
// Open event example
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = new SerialPort('COM220', { autoOpen:true, baudRate: 921600 });


port.on('open', () => {
  console.log('Port Opened');

});

// Switches the port into "flowing mode"
port.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Data:', data);
});

// Read data that is available but keep the stream from entering "flowing mode"
port.on('readable', function () {
  console.log('Data:', port.read());
});
```

Comment: any error on port.on('error',....

Comment: port.on('error' doesn't trigger, so I am assuming there are no errors form the port at least.

Answer (score 0):

I have some ideas:

1. That baud rate is very high and not in the standard for serial ports.  I would start much lower to make sure both devices can match. 38,4?  9600? This is enough to prove your theory.
2. You can log **console.log(port)** the port itself and start comparing behavior and see what you get.
3. The readable mode is different than the normal. What are the results from this?

   port.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log(data.toString());
   }
4. You can make your own buffer by appending a string with the data char.

   var bfr = "";
   port.on('data', function(data) {
   bfr += data.toString(); 
   console.log(bfr);
   }